# How can I mask a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, mask

I am trying to mask an image with something like this:

[image: image to be masked]

Would you please help me?

I am using this code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    UIImage *OrigImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dogs.png"];
    UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
    UIImage *maskedImage = [self maskImage:OrigImage withMask:mask];
    myUIIMage.image = maskedImage;
}
```

Comment: I am the person that wrote the original tutorial.  The mask image is just a simple greyscale image I created in photoshop.  Nothing special about it.  The black area become the "transparent" part of the mask.  Keep in mind that any shade of gray is interpreted as a degree of opacity.  In this manner, masks can be gradients as well which is useful for creating softer borders around a mask.

Comment: This have to be same sized, right?

Comment: hyper-elegant code, thanks.  just a useful link if anyone needs to crop an image before masking...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712797/ios-custom-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-crop-to-square

Comment: Any idea about this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122370/masking-and-reverse-masking-in-imageview-ios

Comment: I urge you to please change the selected answer to the one with almost 3 times as many upvotes. In my opinion it is better in near every way.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

There's an easier way.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
// remember to include Framework as well

CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"] CGImage];
mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourImageView.frame.size.width, yourImageView.frame.size.height);
yourImageView.layer.mask = mask;
yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

For Swift 4 and plus follow code below

```
let mask = CALayer()
mask.contents =  UIImage(named: "right_challenge_bg")?.cgImage as Any
mask.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: leftBGImage.frame.size.width, height: leftBGImage.frame.size.height)
leftBGImage.layer.mask = mask
leftBGImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: thank you but i put this code on `viewDidLoad` but nothing happened !

Comment: You should set the layer property to use the mask, i.e. **[yourImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];**

Comment: Notice that this is necessary to be a UIImageView for this solution. The other solution works with a UIImage only.

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. I am combining this with `UIImage`'s `- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode` to add some gradient masking to the borders of a view.

Comment: Note that to properly mask a `UIScrollView`, you may have to attach the scroll view to a container `UIView` and apply the mask to said container instead.

Comment: I tried this approach but this seems not to be working in iOS 8

Comment: This is not only the easier way, it's the right way to do it! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Anyone know if there is a way to animate the mask? Using the normal animate methods?

Comment: What are <img_width> and <img_height> ?  The mask image, or the imageView image being cropped?

Comment: For Swift code, when put in the mask.contents, should CGImage. Not [CGImage]. If use bracket [ ], it means Array.

Comment: Remove CGImage brackets [ ] Or it WILL NOT work. (Jan '21)

Comment: Author, plz, remove those braces. I've spent 2 hours before realized myself that braces are not needed. And only after that red comments highlighting this. Plz, do it!

Comment: I needed to use a 24-bit PNG with transparency for this to work.

Answer (score 61):

The tutorial uses this method with two parameters: `image` and `maskImage`, these you have to set when you call the method. An example call could look like this, assuming the method is in the same class and the pictures are in your bundle:

Note - amazingly the images do not even have to be the same size.

```
...
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dogs.png"];
UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];

// result of the masking method
UIImage *maskedImage = [self maskImage:image withMask:mask];

...

- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef maskedImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(maskedImageRef);

    // returns new image with mask applied
    return maskedImage;
}
```

After you provided your code I have added some numbers as comments to it for reference. You still have two options. This whole thing is a method, which you are calling somewhere. You don't need to create the images inside it: this reduces the reusability of the method to zero.

To get your code working. Change the methods head (**1.**) to

```
- (UIImage *)maskImageMyImages {
```

Then change the name of the variable in **2.** to

```
UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"];
```

The method will return your masked images so you'll have to call this method in some place.
Can you show us the code where you are calling your method?

Comment: sorry ! where should write `UIImage *image` code ?  !!! because on `-(UIimage *) maskeImage` compiler gives  redefinition error !

Comment: sorry would you please upload a sample code for me ? Iam confused :-s

Comment: Not possible, everything is there. You'll have to show us how you are calling this method, or at least the part in which you'd like to mask your images and show the result.

Comment: my problem is to call it , is it should be something like this ?? (viewDidLoad): see my edited code

Comment: Any idea about the Reverse masking.(Reverse of above process).Means I want to remove the fill area(make it transparent) and Transparent area with fill.

Comment: @NickWeaver is it possible to get a result image like a border of dog. Means set mask to white part of mask image not clear part of mask image.

Answer (score 19):

## Swift 3 - Simplest Solution I Found

I created an `@IBDesignable` for this so you could see the effect right away on your storyboard.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class UIImageViewWithMask: UIImageView {
    var maskImageView = UIImageView()

    @IBInspectable
    var maskImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            maskImageView.image = maskImage
            updateView()
        }
    }

    // This updates mask size when changing device orientation (portrait/landscape)
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateView()
    }

    func updateView() {
        if maskImageView.image != nil {
            maskImageView.frame = bounds
            mask = maskImageView
        }
    }
}
```

### How to use

1. Create a new file and paste in that code above.
2. Add UIImageView to your storyboard (assign an image if you want).
3. On Identity Inspector: Change the custom class to "UIImageViewWithMask" (custom class name above).
4. On Attributes Inspector: Select mask image you
   want to use.

### Example

[image: Masking on Storyboard]

### Notes

- Your mask image should have a transparent background (PNG) for the non-black part.

Answer (score 12):

I tried both code using either CALayer or CGImageCreateWithMask but none of them didn't work for me

But i found out that the problem is with png file format, NOT the code!!
so just to share my finding!

If you want to use

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage
```

you must use **24bit** png **without** alpha channel

If you want to use CALayer mask, you must use (24bit or 8bit) png **with** alpha channel where transparent part of your png will mask the image (for smooth gradient alpha mask.. use 24bit png with alpha channel)

Answer (score 10):

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

        CGImageRef maskImageRef = [maskImage CGImage];

        // create a bitmap graphics context the size of the image
        CGContextRef mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        if (mainViewContentContext==NULL)
            return NULL;

        CGFloat ratio = 0;

        ratio = maskImage.size.width/ image.size.width;

        if(ratio * image.size.height < maskImage.size.height) {
            ratio = maskImage.size.height/ image.size.height;
        }

        CGRect rect1  = {{0, 0}, {maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height}};
        CGRect rect2  = {{-((image.size.width*ratio)-maskImage.size.width)/2 , -((image.size.height*ratio)-maskImage.size.height)/2}, {image.size.width*ratio, image.size.height*ratio}};


        CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, rect1, maskImageRef);
        CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, rect2, image.CGImage);


        // Create CGImageRef of the main view bitmap content, and then
        // release that bitmap context
        CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(mainViewContentContext);
        CGContextRelease(mainViewContentContext);

        UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];

        CGImageRelease(newImage);

        // return the image
        return theImage;
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: thank you, this answer is better then other's speaking about performance with more and bigger images.

Comment: Any idea about the reverse masking.(Reverse of above process).Means I want to remove the fill area(make it transparent) and Transparent area with fill.

Comment: Thanks, this code work better than first !! But i have two troubles : Warning on "kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast" (i cast to "CGBitmapInfo" for fix it) AND does not work for retina images !! can you help me ??...

Comment: @Milanpatel The easy solution is to simply invert your colors in the mask image. :)

Comment: @ZyiOS how can I customize the frame of masked Image. i.e user can increase or decrease the size of masked image.

Answer (score 9):

SWIFT 3 XCODE 8.1

```
func maskImage(image: UIImage, withMask maskImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let maskRef = maskImage.cgImage

    let mask = CGImage(
        maskWidth: maskRef!.width,
        height: maskRef!.height,
        bitsPerComponent: maskRef!.bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel: maskRef!.bitsPerPixel,
        bytesPerRow: maskRef!.bytesPerRow,
        provider: maskRef!.dataProvider!,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: false)

    let masked = image.cgImage!.masking(mask!)
    let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage: masked!)

    // No need to release. Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed.

    return maskedImage

}
```

// for use

```
testImage.image = maskImage(image: UIImage(named: "OriginalImage")!, withMask: UIImage(named: "maskImage")!)
```

Comment: can you give me the picture

Answer (score 3):

Swift version of the accepted solution:

```
func maskImage(image: UIImage, withMask maskImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let maskRef = maskImage.CGImage

    let mask = CGImageMaskCreate(
        CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
        nil,
        false)

    let masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(image.CGImage, mask)
    let maskedImage = UIImage(CGImage: masked)!

    // No need to release. Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed.

    return maskedImage

}
```

Just in case someone need it.

It`s working for me flawlessly.

Comment: Do you have a Swift 3.0 version of this?

Answer (score 2):

we found, that correct answer is not working now and implemented little drop-in class, which helps to mask any image in UIImageView.

It's available here: https://github.com/Werbary/WBMaskedImageView

Example:

```
WBMaskedImageView *imgView = [[WBMaskedImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
imgView.originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"original_image.png"];
imgView.maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask_image.png"];
```

Comment: Good one! It really helped.