# Masking UIImageView on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, masking

How to mask a UIImageView to reveal certain parts of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview

This could be help for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, which means you can access its [layer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW31) property. `CALayer` objects, which you can add as sublayers or set them to the layer property of your UIImageView object, then have a **[mask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW12)** property which should be very useful for what you want to achieve. The layer object to be used as a mask can also be animated with core animation, which is a plus if you want to add dynamic moving masks, for example, to your image.

You have to import the QuartzCore framework to use CALayer — just a reminder.