# How to create own mask in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, masking

[image]

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview)

so don't negative my reputation.

My mask image is : 
[image]

My output is : [image]

```
- (UIImage*)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(
                                        CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false
                                        );

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(image.CGImage, mask);
    CGImageRelease(mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}
```

So how to create my own mask image?

Thanks...

Comment: Mask image should be grayscale with no alpha channel.

Comment: Please tell me , how to edit this image with photoshop..

Comment: First save it as .jpg to remove alpha. Then you can save it back to png.
This image should work already. But you can also convert it to greyscale
(since color information is discarded in this kind of masking) by image->mode->greyscale.

Comment: rokjarc :) thanks now its working great. Thanks friend... thanks alot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try converting image to a grayscale image without alpha.

- Save it as .jpg to remove alpha. Then you can save it back to png.
  This image should work already.
- Convert it to greyscale (since color information is discarded in this kind of masking) by image->mode->greyscale.

[image]