# Mask UIImage issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am using this code for mask UIImage:

```
- (UIImage*)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage2 {
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage2.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    CGImageRelease(mask);

    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
    CGImageRelease(masked);

    return maskedImage;
}
```

In the IOS 6 it work perfect and mask all the UIImage but i try it now on my iPhone 4 with IOS 4.3 and noticed that some of the images mask but have a black background as you can see in this image:
[image]

This is the mask image:
[image]

As you can noticed the first image is mask but it's have a black in the side, and the other images mask perfectly. i noticed that it happen with the same images every time.
Any idea what can be the problem?

====================================

Edit

I try to save the images to my document and after a look on them it's look like the `maskedImage` i saved without the black border,any idea why it show me this black border?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992290/how-to-create-own-mask-in-ios?rq=1

Comment: @Daij-Djan i tried what wrote in this post and it still give some of the image with black border