# How to animate a CALayer attached to UIImageView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I am using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview) proposed by Bartosz to add a mask to an UIImageView. It works fine.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"] CGImage];
mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 100.0);
yourImageView.layer.mask = mask;
yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

In addition, I want to animate the mask, e.g. sliding the mask to the right, so that at the end of the animation, the mask is not applied to the UIImageView any more.

In my specific case, the mask uses a fully transparent image, so the UIImageView is not visible at the initial state (which works fine), but is expected to be so at the end of the animation. However, the idea may be reused to any other use case were masks need to be animated.

The idea is to manipulate the x-origin portion of the frame of the mask. So, I came up with this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2
                      delay: 0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                         CGRect maskFrame = yourImageView.layer.mask.frame;
                         maskFrame.origin.x = 320.0;
                         yourImageView.layer.mask.frame = maskFrame;
                     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

Unfortunately, the mask is applied to the whole UIImageView at any time, it's not sliding to the right.

**UPDATE 1:**

This is the code I am actually using the set up the view and mask: It's a UITableViewCell.

APPCell.m (APPCell.h "extends" UITableViewCell)

```
#import "APPCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface APPCell()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *menu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CALayer *menuMask;
...
@end

@implementation APPCell
...

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self.menu = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 88.0)];
[self.menu setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.menu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_back"]];
[self addSubview:self.menu];

self.menuMask = [CALayer layer];
self.menuMask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_mask"] CGImage];
self.menuMask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 88.0);
self.menu.layer.mask = self.menuMask;
self.menu.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
...
```

Instead of animating with the help of UIKit, I am now using implicit animation of CoreAnimation to move the mask layer:

APPCell.m

```
...
- (void)swipeLeft
{
self.menuMask.position = CGPointMake(-320.0, 0.0);
}
...
```

I can confirm that swipeLeft is called. I expect the mask "to be gone" and to see the **[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_back"]]**, which I do when I uncomment **self.menu.layer.mask = self.menuMask**.

**Solution:**

Instead of setting the content on the CALayer, I set the background color to white. This is the code I am using:

```
self.menuSubMenuMask = [CALayer layer];
self.menuSubMenuMask.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
self.menuSubMenuMask.frame = CGRectMake(320.0, 0.0, 320.0, 88.0);
self.tableCellSubMenu.layer.mask = self.menuSubMenuMask;
self.tableCellSubMenu.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

In order to show the UIImageView the CALayer is applied to, the CALayer must NOT be "above" the UIImageView.

Comment: Presumably you mean `maskFrame = imageView.layer.mask.frame;` and the expected reverse two lines below that?

Comment: Tommy, yes, thanks, you are correct and i updated it, but unfortunately, it was just a so-specific typo and thus, doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation with UIKit of UIViews is much more limited than using Core Animation directly. In particular what you are trying to animate is not one of animatable properties of a UIView. In addition as clarified in the [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW2):

> **Note:** If your view hosts custom layer objects—that is, layer objects without an associated view—you must use Core Animation to animate any changes to them.

This is the case in your example. You have added a CALayer to your view and UIKit will not be able to animate the result for you. On the other hand you can use Core Animation directly to animate the motion of your mask layer. You should be able to do this easily using implicit animation as described in the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW1). Please note that from the list of [CALayer Animatable Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005942-SW1) that frame is not animatable. Instead you should use `position`.

Comment: Thanks Torrey, what you are saying makes totally sense and is also proven by the docs. Unfortunately, I still can't get it to work. I am now using "self.menuMask.position = CGPointMake(-320.0, 0.0);" to move the mask layer to the left. I added additional code I am using in my previous post.

Comment: Do you see any change at all when you use `self.menuMask.position = CGPointMake(-320.0, 0.0)` to animate moving the mask? Note that this is not exactly what you want since `position` is the center point of the CALayer. So to completely move it out of the way you'll want `self.menuMask.position = CGPointMake(-320.0-44.0, 0.0)`. Still you should be able to see some effect from your animation if things are working.

Comment: Nothing, no animation. I assumed setting "self.menuMask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 88.0);" causes to mask to be of size 320.0 x 88.0, thus I assumed "self.menuMask.position = CGPointMake(-320.0, 0.0);" should do it. But anyway, no visible changes at all.

Comment: (Doh! Yes of course, your position change will definitely move the layer out of the way.) If the implicit animation is not working for you, you should try an explicit animation. This has the advantage of being easier to debug since you can see when the animation starts and terminates from the `CAAnimation` delegate. [Apple Tech QA1620](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1620/_index.html) gives sample code on how to animate an CALayer's position using explicit animation.

Comment: While this answer didn't really solved my problem (I made a mistake elsewhere, so above), I accepted this as the answer because of the Apple Tech QA1620 link you provided, which might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something you want by using `CATransition`, although this might not be the solution you want:

1) At first, set mask for your layer just as you did

2) When you want to remove mask and reveal your image, use the following code:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
transition.duration = 1.0;
[mask addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
imageView.layer.mask.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"black.png"].CGImage;
```

The main trick here - we created transition animation for our mask layer, so this animation will be applied when you change any (i'm not sure about any) property of mask layer. Now we set mask's content to completely black image to remove masking at all - now we've got smooth pushing animation where our masked image is going to the left and unmasked image is getting into its place

Comment: Using the black image works, too. However, I am using a white color. Anyway, both approaches work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use CoreAnimation itself:

```
CGPoint fromPoint = mask.position;
CGPoint toPoint = CGPointMake(fromPoint.x*3.0, fromPoint.y);

mask.position = toPoint; // CoreAnimation animations do *not* persist

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:fromPoint];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toPoint];
animation.duration = 4.0f;

[mask addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```