# Create iOS mask image on the fly

Tags: ios, graphics, ios6, masking

I got an image I want to mask on the fly. The mask is basically shaped like a part-circle and changes in volume from time to time. Therefor I need to create an in-memory image, draw the mask circle stuff to it and do the masking on the original image like described in [How to Mask an UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview).

The thing is that I got no idea how to create an in-memory image I may use for masking and I can apply basic drawing opperations on.t

Answer (score 0):

If your mask is only a semi-circle, it might be easier to create a clipping path with `CGContext*` calls and draw your image as a `CGImage` with the clipping path applied. See [the documentation for `CGContextClip()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) for details.