# UIImagePickerController on iOS 7: Square mode?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working with iOS 7 now, trying to get the UIImagePickerController to let the user select a square mode since it's a feature in iOS 7 now. Is there something I need to enable to allow this swipe? Relevant code posted below, though it's pretty standard.

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraView = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraView.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraView.delegate = (id)self;
[self presentViewController:cameraView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I've been scouring the messy iOS 7 documentation that's available, but I can't even tell if they changed the developer library at all - I don't see ANYTHING new in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Custom UIImagePickerController Camera Crop to Square](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712797/ios-custom-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-crop-to-square)

Answer (score 8):

set allowEditing to YES.
from the result dict use the key UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage

then you will have the squared image.

i find no way to let the user select, which format he want :(

Comment: Furthermore, there seems to be an unfixed bug in iOS 6, 7, and 8 where the screen that allowEditing brings up doesn't actually let the user move the photo around.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the iOS 7 header for `UIImagePickerController` in Xcode, and I do not see new API for 7.0 or a square photo mode. The square photo mode appears to be a feature of the app, not of `UIImagePickerController`.