# swift 2 open camera in square mode only

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

So far I have the camera working fine, it opens up in the regular format. But I want the only option to be square format.

Here is my code so far.

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can open camera in square format using UIImagePickerController. What you can do is set UIImagePickerController allowEditing to YES and from the result dict use the key UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage then you will have the squared image so you code becomes .

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Another way around is mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17713092/1180206) . 
You can use the logic from answer to write the code in swift.

But if you want to look in details and try out doing some more  have a look into

- [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/),
- [AVCaptureConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/),
- [AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/)
- [AVCaptureDeviceInput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDeviceInput_Class/)
- [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/)
- [AVCaptureStillImageOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/index.html)
- [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_Class/)
- [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/index.html)
- [CoreImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)

Also look at apple [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, im trying to figure out the answer hyper link but I can't make sense of it....is it possible for you to put it in context or an example. Thanks

Comment: My answer have thee options . First is using editing, Second is a way around and third is not using UIImagePickerController. For third I posted link to apple SquareCam sample that is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: first two options are straight forward do you also need help (code) about these?

Comment: Im still kind of new to swift, but aren't those answers in objective C? I apologize if i'm mistaken

Comment: Yes Apple sample and answer is in Objc but you can use logic to write code in swift.