# Change cropper size of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I want to change the cropper size of UIImagePickerView from (320*320) to (320 * 240) .

I have searched it everywhere, but none them is working fine for me . 
I have used GKImagePicker https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker

But when i just drag its classes to my project . It gives me error . What to do ???

[image]

Any help much appreciated .

Need to resize cropper like in image below

[image]

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: i just have implemented uiimagepickercontroller . I don't know how to set cropper dimensions @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: see once may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712797/ios-custom-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-crop-to-square

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041732/set-dimensions-for-uiimagepickercontroller-move-and-scale-cropbox

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Its not helping me

Comment: @sschale - Can you provide some sample code  ?

Comment: @sschale - I know this is duplicate question . But i am not able to implement this cropper with those previous posts .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those errors are fixed by importing UIKit/UIKit.h to GKImagePicker.h