# How do I mask a UIImageView without use of another UIImage, just simply defining a simple shape like a rounded-square?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer

Say I have an image of a picturesque landscape. A rectangle, say `300x200` in dimensions.

How would I go about masking a square of say, `200x200` of the image with rounded corners into a `UIImageView` I could then present to the user?

I see tons of examples such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview) where they go over how to use a `UIImage` as the mask, but I just need a simple shape (a rounded square).

How would I go about accomplishing a simple mask like this without a `UIImage`?

Comment: You can't just define a path or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CAShapeLayer` to mask your `UIImageView`. Code is as followings:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```