# SKCropNode masking edge anti-aliasing

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, antialiasing, masking, skcropnode

I created a circular mask and animate a sprite inside the mask by using sprite kit SKCropNode class. But the edge of the mask looks pixellated.

Is there a way to use anti-aliasing to smooth the edges?

Comment: could you share the code you used to achieve the mask?

Comment: does is appear pixelated on the simulator only or the device too??

Comment: According to specs, it will definitely have jagged edges, as the SKCropNode uses a boolean (0 or 1) alpha value, not a byte value (say, 0 to 255).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to mask any SKNode/SKSpriteNode with an anti-aliasing effect - you can use SKEffectNode instead of SKCropNode. It works with animated nodes as well. Here is an example:

```
// Set up your node
SKNode *nodeToMask = [SKNode node];
// ...

// Set up the mask node
SKEffectNode *maskNode = [SKEffectNode node];

// Create a filter
CIImage *maskImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_mask_image"].CGImage];
CIFilter *maskFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceInCompositing"
                                  keysAndValues:@"inputBackgroundImage", maskImage, nil];
// Set the filter
maskNode.filter = maskFilter;

// Add childs
[maskNode addChild:nodeToMask];
[scene addChild:maskNode];
```

Answer (score 3):

From the official docs:

> If the pixel in the mask has an alpha value of less than 0.05, the
>   image pixel is masked out.

So, SKCropNode doesn't support per pixel alpha values. It either draws the pixels or it doesn't. If alpha (as is used by anti-aliasing) is important to you, you should consider alternative routes. For example:

[How to Mask an UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview)

Answer (score -1):

As of now (June 2018) I can confirm that the SKCropNode will do per-pixel alpha blending. If the crop node has an SKSpriteNode as a mask, and the mask node uses a texture with an anti-aliased mask image, the crop node will do the proper blending.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing my man. October 2018. Perhaps you can expand on this?