# SpriteKit mask with transparency / opacity / alpha

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, tvos

**How can I create a masking effect that uses alpha instead of a hard edge when using SpriteKit?**

I am aware of [SKCropNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKCropNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKCropNode), but this is not what I need. I would like to create the equivalent of masking in Photoshop, or Illustrator where either opacity or greyscale is used to determine the transparency of the masked image.

Initially, I would like to use this to create a wipe effect, but there are various uses in the future.

I need it to be possible to animate as well.

[image]

Comment: SKCropNode is exactly what you need,  and if you put a SKCropNode as a mask for an SKCropNode,  you get alpha cropping, not just on off cropping

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I was not able to make your suggestion work. Could you provide some example code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SKCropNode masking edge anti-aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619378/skcropnode-masking-edge-anti-aliasing)