# Swift How to mask UIView content

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I should mask this rounded UIImageView:

[image]

to get this kind of result:

[image]

Is it possible obtain it using some core's utility? (maybe using something like UIBezierPath or CAShapeLayer).

I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Here's a good article: https://medium.com/@peteliev/layer-masking-for-beginners-c18a0a10743

Comment: Here's a somewhat similar shape: https://github.com/mattneub/MessageBubble

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy and smart way to deal with that task, I don't know if it's the best way to do it but it works!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639398/6925344