# Mask UIImage with moving mask using Pan gesture, Rotate gesture, Pinch Gesture iOS

Tags: ios, image, uigesturerecognizer, masking

i want to mask UIImage with moving mask image using Pan, Rotate, Pinch gesture can anyone help me for this i want to create pip like image but pip image is moving and mask must move accordingly

Comment: Show the code that you've tried so far and describe where you are running into problems. Difficult to help if you only say what you *want* to do, without telling us what you're *doing*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947269/how-to-move-and-crop-image-from-masked-image here is the same concept but the the difference is i want to move pip frame over the original image and mask the original image with mask-image

Comment: OK - so have you tried modifying that code to do what you want?

Comment: yap!! thanks for your response but i have solved my problem ..... :) working successfully thank you .....