# UIViewContentModeCenter Adds Padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I want to display thumbnails of various size images in a `UIImageView`. If the image is too big to fit in the `UIImageView`, I want to only display the amount of the photo that fits in the `UIImageView`, with the center of the original image in the center of the `UIImageView`.

I am currently doing this by setting `imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;` and `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`. This is almost working, except there is a small amount of what appears to be padding inside the layer of the `UIImageView`. When I try to add a corner radius I can see that the corners are not fully rounded.

When I leave `imageView.contentMode` as the default value, there is no padding on the sides of the image, but the image is scaled strangely, and not how I want.

Why am I getting this issue with `UIViewContentModeCenter`, and is there a way to fix it? If not, how can I crop my image on the fly so that I do not have to use `UIViewContentModeCenter`, but only show the center portion of the image that fits the `UIImageView`?

Below is how the view looks with `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter`. See how there is extra padding on the left and right, although when I log the width and x origin of the `imageView` they appear to be the same as the label above.

[image: With <code>imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter. See padding added to sides.</code>]

Below is the same exact code as above, but with the default setting for `imageView.contentMode`. See how there is no padding added, but the image is warped.

[image: Same constraints and UI setup as above, but with default setting for <code>imageView.contentMode</code>]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIViewContentModeCenter keeps the proportions of the imageView, so, when you display it, can show a padding because the image has more height than width, or viceversa.

The default contentMode is UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, so when you use it, the image is expanded in every direction to fill the imageView. That's why you don't see any padding.

If you want to fill the imageView and keep image proportions, then you should use `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`

Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect. `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I see somethings cut you UIImageView on the left and right side. The width of UIImageView (with UIViewContentModeCenter) is less than normal. I'm not sure about your problem with `UIViewContentModeCenter`. 
But there are some ways to work around:

1. Add UIImageView to UIView, with `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;` and cornerRadius UIView.
2. Use mask for UIImageView: [How to Mask an UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview)

Hope this helps.