# UIImageView Pie Mask in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, mask

After searching numerous sources on how to mask an image in **Swift**, I've found many that utilize UIImage rather than UIImageView. It's getting quite confusing because they are almost similar yet they don't share some of the same subclasses & properties.

I have an image that will be added into a stacks view although I'd like this image to be masked with a circular shape with a fixed start and end angle.

**Example**:

[image: Original Picture and Desired Mask Result]

***Original Picture and Desired Mask Result***

**I'd like to emphasize that I am simulating a pie being sliced out so essentially I am cropping an image with the Pie's size.**

Here's what I've attempted so far to get started (and I keep failing)...

```
let testPicture:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "myPicture"))
testPicture.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
testPicture.layer.borderWidth = 1
testPicture.clipsToBounds = true
testPicture.layer.masksToBounds = true
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

// ???
// UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(startAngle), endAngle: CGFloat(endAngle), clockwise: clockwise).CGPath

self.myStackView.addArrangedSubview(testPicture)
self.myStackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I just can't figure out how to apply the same implementation of masking images with geometric functions when other sources out there solely use UIImage.

**New Code (Attempt) to Generate Pie Mask**

```
let center = CGPointMake(testPicture.frame.size.width / 2, testPicture.frame.size.height / 2)
let radius = CGFloat((CGFloat(testPicture.frame.size.width) - CGFloat(1.0)) / 2)
let midX = (testPicture.layer.frame.width-testPicture.layer.frame.width)/2
let midY = (testPicture.layer.frame.height-testPicture.layer.frame.height)/2

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: midX , y: midY), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(10), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

testPicture.layer.mask = maskLayer
testPicture.clipsToBounds = true
testPicture.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: `UIImage` and `UIImageView` are completely different and share nothing.  A `UIImage` corresponds to the model of an image, it contains, among other things, the raw bits of the image, and mechanisms for reading/writing images from various formats.  `UIImageView` corresponds to the view of the image, it's responsible only for the DISPLAY of a `UIImage`

Comment: You'll want to add your `UIBezierPath` to a `CAShapeLayer` and use that to mask your `UIImageView`'s layer. Although I'm not sure what you're trying to do by setting `masksToBounds` to false, then `clipsToBounds` to true... The view's `clipsToBounds` is just a forwarding property for the underlying layer's `masksToBounds`. They do the same thing.

Comment: You're right! Whoops, a silly mistake. I'm starting to believe UIBezierPath won't give me my desired Pie masking. Currently looking for the correct drawing! :-|

Comment: In your new code you never set the frame of the `maskLayer` - you need to set that to the bounds of the `testPicture`

Comment: Since you're mutating the question, I'm not sure what you're actually asking at this point.

Comment: I'm not necessarily mutating the question. I am still trying to mask the initial image of testPicture with a Pie shape just as my image depicts. Not sure whether UIBezierPath or your suggestion is bringing me closer to the solution. Still attempting to figure this out.

Comment: Perhaps the best solution is just to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview then.

Comment: I beg to differ. This is not written in Swift and I have already experimented with the other answers to simulate the Pie cropping on the image. It was a no-go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mask a layer you assign a separate layer to the `mask` property.  In this case, I think what you're looking for is:

```
testPicture.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

Comment: Good answer! This has helped me get a step further as I tried to accomplish the desired result; however, I just realized the geometric function I had to draw a PIE wasn't the right one. Apparently I have to use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()... I think. If that is the case, the masking won't work. :-( I've updated my code

Comment: The easiest approach may be to create your pie as a CGPath and then create a CAShapeLayer from that, but that's a different question :)

Comment: Which I now see that you're doing...  Given that you're using `UIBezierPath` you shouldn't need to worry about the graphics context.

Comment: I am actually using a PNG image so I suppose using UIBezierPath to draw a Pie in terms of masking it, as my image shows, would be the solution. The PNG image would be the gradient square (or perhaps a picture of Apple Pie), and I would want to simulate a cropped result of slices taken out from that image.

Comment: Ok. I've figured it out and your suggestion worked; however, it does not mask within the same size of the subview's testPicture boundaries and .ScaleAspectFit contentMode property. I suppose this will be a follow up question elsewhere so I'll thank you for helping me get ahead!

Comment: Follow up question in case anyone is interested and would like to see where this follows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36162215/stack-view-scaleaspectfit-mask-resize-in-swift