# ios - How to do the clipping mask effect using the two images

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bitmap

Am having the mask image and the normal image i want to do the exact clipping mask effect and want to set that image to the UIImageView.

[image]

In this PIP Camera app they did this

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/hua-zhong-hua-xiang-ji-nice/id521922264?mt=8

And i tried this

[How to Mask an UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757386/how-to-mask-an-uiimageview)
exactly what they suggest but no luck

Could anyone here give an idea of how we do that?

Comment: Check out ImageMagicks : http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/

Comment: And another simple way is to use layer.mask property. But in that case you will need Masking image having Black and White tones.

Comment: I tried the layer mask property  //  CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
    mask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.png"] CGImage];
    mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    _BackgroundImage.layer.mask = mask;
    _BackgroundImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    self.BackgroundImage.layer.mask = mask;
    [_BackgroundImage.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

Comment: It's not worked for me

Comment: CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"m0_mask.png"];
    maskLayer.contents = (id)mask.CGImage;
    maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
    maskLayer.frame = self.BackgroundImage.bounds;
    _BackgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"];
    _BackgroundImage.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self.view addSubview:_BackgroundImage];

Comment: Thanks man its working

Comment: @Vignesh in my case it doesn't make a proper image. The selected image(Lady image) is replaced with mask image.

Comment: Can you please show your output